# Loop accepts first set of input and then reuses that value

Tags: c++, loops, io, codeblocks

I am currently learning C++ in school and one of our projects is to create a program to calculate a budget.  When I run my program, the loop that accepts the input for item cost will take the input once and then reuse that value each time it loops back.  I have already searched online for a solution and my teacher is just as confused about it as I am. It could be that there is a problem with Codeblocks but I have already tried it with a different editor. If anyone knows how I can fix it, that would be great.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Declares variables
    float itemCount = 0;
    float taxPercent = 0;
    float itemCost = 0;
    bool taxable = true;
    float totalTaxable = 0;
    float totalNontaxable = 0;
    float total = 0;

    //Receive user input
    cout << "How many items to you have to buy: ";
    cin >> itemCount;
    cout << "\nWhat is the tax percentage (do not include the % sign): ";
    cin >> taxPercent;

    //This code runs once for every item
    while (itemCount > 0){

        //Receive the remaining user input
        cout << "\nWhat is the cost of the item: ";
        cin >> itemCost;

        cout << "\nIs the item taxable (Please use either true or false): ";
        cin >> taxable;

        //Adds the item cost to either the taxable or nontaxable variables
        if (taxable == true){
            totalTaxable += itemCost;
            cout << "true";
        }  else{
            totalNontaxable += itemCost;
            cout <<"false";
        }

        itemCount -= 1;
    }
    total = (totalTaxable * (1 + (taxPercent / 100))) + totalNontaxable;
    cout << "\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    cout << "You must earn $";
    cout << total;
    cout << " to meet this budget\n\n";
}
```

Comment: You can't use `cin` on a boolean, use a char with Y and N and do some char comparisons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comment, you can't use cin on boolean. From the doc :

> The standard input stream is a source of characters determined by the environment.

So here's your fixed code (which will accept `Y` and nothing else) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Declares variables
    float itemCount = 0;
    float taxPercent = 0;
    float itemCost = 0;
    char taxable = '';
    float totalTaxable = 0;
    float totalNontaxable = 0;
    float total = 0;

    //Receive user input
    cout << "How many items to you have to buy: ";
    cin >> itemCount;
    cout << "\nWhat is the tax percentage (do not include the % sign): ";
    cin >> taxPercent;

    //This code runs once for every item
    while (itemCount > 0){

        //Receive the remaining user input
        cout << "\nWhat is the cost of the item: ";
        cin >> itemCost;

        cout << "\nIs the item taxable (Please use Y for Yes): ";
        cin >> taxable;

        //Adds the item cost to either the taxable or nontaxable variables
        if (taxable == 'Y'){
            totalTaxable += itemCost;
            cout << "true";
        }  else{
            totalNontaxable += itemCost;
            cout <<"false";
        }

        itemCount -= 1;
    }
    total = (totalTaxable * (1 + (taxPercent / 100))) + totalNontaxable;
    cout << "\n--------------------------------------------------\n";
    cout << "You must earn $";
    cout << total;
    cout << " to meet this budget\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly now.  However, I had to add in a character when declaring the taxable variable. It would not compile without assigning a value.